# UIHostingController throws

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to load from a UIViewController a SwiftUI based view that reads a json local to the bundle. The code and binding in a swiftUI only project works fine, when I leverage the UIHostingController I get an error for which I am seeking help to fix.

```
class ProgramsListVCHost : UIHostingController<ProgramsList>, Storyboarded {
    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: ProgramsList())

    }
}
```

The code above crashes because I didn't pass what I should have to cause the init of the model.

```
super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: ProgramsList().environmentObject(ProgramUserData()))
```

However, if I do that the compiler demands that I cast the whole thing to the underlying class ProgramList (Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'ProgramsList')

If I do apply the recommended fix, the code crashes with the error:

> Could not cast value of type
>   'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent>>'
>   (0x7fff89d0ec68) to 'bikeit.ProgramsList' (0x110477328). 2019-11-15
>   14:36:26.049041-0500 bikeit[13658:8386085] Could not cast value of
>   type 'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent>>'
>   (0x7fff89d0ec68) to 'bikeit.ProgramsList' (0x110477328). (lldb)

I don't understand how to initialize the object that I must pass in order to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, it is because your declared content `UIHostingController<ProgramsList>` is `ProgramsList`, so it is expected in initialiser, but you pass to it output of `.environmentObject`, which is `SwiftUI.ModifiedContent`, so types checking fails and you get compiler error.

It is not clear your needs, but possible solution could be as follows:

```
class ProgramsListVCHost : UIHostingController<AnyView>, Storyboarded {
    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: AnyView(ProgramsList().environmentObject(ProgramUserData())))
    }
}
```

**Update:** found alternate

```
class ProgramsListVCHost : UIHostingController<ProgramsListVCHost.MyView>, Storyboarded {

    // Internal view
    struct MyView: View {
      var body: some View {
         ProgramsList().environmentObject(ProgramUserData())
      }
    }

    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: MyView())
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a new instance of a ProgramUserData, I use a singleton to hold the reference, and its works like a charm. Thank you